# doing arithmetic operations on extra large numbers in query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I save very large numbers in my database (usually with 50+ digits) and then need to run queries like (`id` is the label of column where the numbers are saved):

```
WHERE id % 2 = 0
```

I tried to use `varchar` data type for this column and although no error is generated while running the query, the returned result is mathematically wrong (the returned ids are not even).

1. does MySQL convert `varchar` to `int` while running my query and so is overflow the reason of the mistake in results?
2. what is the best choice for saving such large numbers on which I can do arithmetic operation latter? if `decimal` is the best candidate then what if I need to save the numbers with 100 digits?

Comment: is 65 digits enough?

Comment: For to test `WHERE id % 2 = 0` it is enough to test the most last digit for the same expression `WHERE RIGHT(id, 1) % 2 = 0` which does not need in long numbers processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *only* choice is to cast to a numeric/decimal value explicitly.  In MySQL, that supports up to 65 digits of precision.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be3b434005b47e180b2c5eb97d67b67e) is a db<>fiddle with an example.  Or an [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b64b905af9e0ea2e19e7e0c112b6bbb) using `%`.

Comment: so I would better change the data type to `decimal(65,0)`. right?!

Comment: @Soheil . . . The default scale is `0`, but there is definitely no harm in being explicit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff does % in fact work on decimal fields that exceed bigint range?  I see the doc says "This function is safe to use with BIGINT values." which is far from reassuring

Comment: @ysth . . . It certainly *seems* to work (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffa1cdc3367c76650e7dcc691752da34).  Of course, examples of it working are not proof that it always works, so that comment is beguiling.